# Phonegap build online - iOS ATS configuration

Tags: cordova, ios9

I have some trouble with Ajax call to my http server with new ATS function built in in iOS 9 Iphones

How i can set configuration key in .plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

in config.xml file for online build with Phonegap?

Thanks

Comment: use the ats plugin https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-transport-security